# How to close section in FlutterFire?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I created a new account to be able to better manage my projects in firebase, but with the FlutterFire tool I already started session with a different account, how can I close cetion in that account in FlutterFire and start with the new one? **i would greatly appreciate your help!**

Try to read in the project documentation but do not find that information :C

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to sign in a different user in Firebase Authentication, you can:

- Either first call `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();` (as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/password-auth#next_steps)) and then sign in the other user.
- Or immediately sign in the other user. That will automatically sign out the previous user, as the Firebase Authentication SDK can only have one current user at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Enter: 'firebase logout' in terminal
If you havent setup firebase, set that first.
https://github.com/chriso23/firebase-cli